# Proper use of MIDIPacketListAdd (CoreMIDI)

Tags: macos, core-audio, coremidi

I'm trying to use CoreAudio's  MIDIPacketListAdd by doing this (on mac):

MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time, len, data);

I was thinking of calling the method multiple times before sending it out, so that my packetList will have > 1 packet in it. 
However when I do so the numPackets never increases, and what I am getting is packetList->packet[0] with the an ever increasing packet[0].data.

1) What's the correct way to use this method? I've looked at several examples, including the one from "Learning Core Audio" - they all seem to be sending just one packet.

2) Is there any performance improvement if I pack multiple packets in 1 packet list over sending 1 packet list with 1 packet multiple times?

Thanks, appreciate any help regarding this.

Edit for follow-up : Here's how I init the packet list

```
#define PACKETLIST_SIZE 512

- (void) initPacketList {

    if (packetList) {
        free(packetList);
        packetList = NULL;
    }

    packetList = (MIDIPacketList *)malloc(PACKETLIST_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    currentPacket = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
}

- (void) clearPacketList {

    packetList->numPackets = 0;
        currentPacket = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
}

- (void) addPacketToPacketList:(Byte*) data ofLength:(int) len {

    NSLog(@"length %d", len); 
    //NSLog(@"%lld", mach_absolute_time());
    currentPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time, len, data);

    //if (!currentPacket) exit(1);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The answer is in the documentation for `MIDIPacketListAdd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMidi/Reference/MIDIServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010316-CHMIDIServiceshFunctions-SW9).

> **Return Value**
>
> Returns null if there was not room in the packet for the event; otherwise returns a packet pointer which should be passed as curPacket in a subsequent call to this function.

So you probably want something like:

```
currentPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time, len, data);
```

Be sure to check if `currentPacket` is NULL after each time.

Performance should be better if you put multiple packets in one packet list, since you're making fewer cross-process requests to the MIDI server, but honestly it's unlikely to be noticeable on a modern Mac.

*Edit:* here's what you're doing wrong.

```
packetList = (MIDIPacketList *)malloc(PACKETLIST_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(char)` is always 1 in the C language, by definition. `malloc(PACKETLIST_SIZE)` is all you need.

```
currentPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time, len, data);
```

This gave me a compiler warning, because you are passing the *address* of the `mach_absolute_time` function, not calling the function. You meant:

```
currentPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time(), len, data);
```

Once I did that, I saw `packetList->numPackets` increase as expected.

However, note two things:

- If you want to send the MIDI data immediately, just provide a timestamp of `0`.
- If you call `MIDIPacketListAdd` with the same timestamp as the previous call, then it just concatenates your data to the previous packet. You will see `packetList->numPackets` and `currentPacket` stay the same, but `currentPacket->length` will increase.

That's why you didn't see `packetList->numPackets` increase: the address of `mach_absolute_time` is a constant, so your "timestamp" was the same every time.

Comment: hi Kurt, I am doing exactly the above, but my data is still being stuffed in one packet when I check it using the debugger. packetList->packet[0]->data gets longer when the next piece of data should be in the next packet packet[1].

Comment: Another question would be, if my packetList->packet[0]->data is say 9 bytes, would the last 6 bytes be ignored by the synth/virtual instrument I am sending it to?

Comment: The debugger is misleading you. A `MIDIPacket` is a variable-length structure -- it has 6 bytes of header (4 bytes `timeStamp`, 2 bytes `length`), then between 1 and 65535 bytes of data. The `MIDIPacketList` is just one or more `MIDIPackets` stored contiguously in memory. The problem is: you cannot really represent variable-length structures in C. So, you can't say `packet[1]` to get to the second packet -- neither the compiler nor the debugger will do the right thing. Use `MIDIPacketListNext`, or look at the raw memory directly.

Comment: Also, your packet's `length` should be the exact length of the data you want to send. If you want it to send 3 bytes, then the length should be `3`. I have no earthly idea why you would set it to `9` and then add 6 extra bytes of garbage. CoreMIDI would (probably) send it out as-is, but if it isn't valid MIDI, the receiver could do just about anything.

Comment: Ah I c.. another thing I find strange. Even though I call currentPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time, len, data) 3 times before sending out the packetlist, the packetlist->numPackets is still 1 every time I print it.  Is this something I update myself?

Comment: I'm not setting the packet length to > 3.len in MIDIPacketListAdd is always 3.  Sorry to confuse u, when I said 9 I was referring to the value i saw in the debugger.

Comment: `packetList->numPackets` should increase by 1 after each call to `MIDIPacketListAdd`. Are you sure that `PACKETLIST_SIZE` is large enough? If it is too small, then one of the `MIDIPacketListAdd` calls would fail, leave the packet list unchanged, and return NULL.

Comment: Hi Kurt I updated my question with more code. The PACKETLIST_SIZE is 512. Am I doing anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Tried your code, and edited. I had forgotten what happened when you provided the same timestamp to subsequent calls of `MIDIPacketListAdd`.

Comment: Indeed it works - thanks so much for your help! You are a midi god! XD Pardon me for the rookie mistakes...